# How can I enable the users delete and edit the objects they create in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web

Now I have a model called lyric. The detail is as below:

```
class Lyric(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.CharField(max_length = 12000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

I have a form that user can create lyric. Next I want to enable the user can edit and delete the lyrics. Now I have implemented the form of editing and the function of delete. But how can I limit the permission? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Simply compare `request.user` and `lyric.user` - if they're the same, the `Lyric` belongs to the user.

Comment: Have a look on the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: @henrikstroem Thanks guys! I basically know the logic in the back end. But how can I, let 'say just the creators can see the edit and delete button in their own page? Many thanks!

Comment: @yobichi In your template, put the buttons inside an if structure checking the user.

Comment: @henrikstroem I succeed on the template now. But where should I put the compare? views.py or models.py? Thanks!

Comment: @yobichi You can put the compare in your template - or in the view if you prefer, and then pass the result to the template.

Comment: @henrikstroem But the user can access the edit form through the url directly even there is no button accessible for them. And put the logic directly on template is kinda not safe, I think...

Comment: @yobichi You still have to prevent the action from taking place in the view that would handle the deletion - the other is just to prevent showing the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick hint. In your views, you can do this:

```
if request.user == lyric.user:
    lyric.delete() # or save edits
else:
    raise PermissionDenied # import it from django.core.exceptions
```

In your templates, you can access the logged in user as `request.user` or simply `user`:

```
{% if request.user == lyric.user %}
    <a href="/link/to/view/">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Thanks! Thanks! So now I know a magic named PermissionDenied :) But actually I would like to learn the using of permission.....